# What does the is_sparse mean in StreamDef?

Tags: deep-learning, azure-cognitive-services, cntk

I'm new to `CNTK` and quite confused about the `is_sparse` argument in StreamDef. Does it mean the input file has to be in some specific format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means that the corresponding field in the CTF file is expected to be formatted as zero or more feature_index:feature_value pairs.

Comment: What does `be formatted as zero` mean?  I haven't come across such examples.

Comment: For example you can have |name feature: value |other_name feature: value |one_more_name |last_name feature: value. This example has all features equal to zero for one_more_name.